# Убрать отображение zoom в Webview

Tags: android, webview

Как избавиться от кастомного контрола в WebView ?

делаю так:

```
myBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

изменение размера происходит, но при этом появляется компонент в правом углу (+|-)

Answer (score 1):

То есть вы включаете zoom controls, и при этом недовольны, что они отображаются?

Если вам нужна лишь возможность масштабирования, без визуальных контролов, то:

```
myBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
myBrowser.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
```

Comment: мне нужна возможность масштабировать с помощью мультитача как в браузере, но без отображения визуального контрола

Comment: Так для этого ничего не нужно делать! WebView работает так при стандартных настройках.

Comment: пишу     
WebView myBrowser = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);   
myBrowser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/" +files[i] );   
мультитач как в браузере не происходит

Comment: @gadfil: попробуйте также `myBrowser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте, вот это. Должно работать для **api 11 и выше**

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);  
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(true);
```

В общем  случае, изучите вот [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview)

Comment: увы и это не работает (( api 14 и выше

Answer (score 0):

В отображаемом контенте можно убрать зум HTML тегом. Не совсем то, но в моем случае этого достаточно.
User-scalable=no

Answer (score 0):

Решено!

```
myBrowser.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
myBrowser.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
myBrowser.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]